# How to remove default index.html mapping in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring boot + React JS in my application.

When user logins to the application, I'm building user details object inside my controller and puts the user details object into session attribute. Then controller tries to return ModelAndView object with views as index.html.

Sometimes index.html is rendered first by default before calling the user details method. I wants to remove this default index.html mapping behavior and always it's has to render from controller's MAV.

I tried couple of options by putting setCachable as false and must revalidated header but nothing worked out for me.

Appreciate any assistance on this.

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331929/spring-catch-all-route-for-index-html