# How to serve single-page app in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, single-page-application

I'm trying to do something very simple in Spring Boot:

1. Serve my api calls from /api
2. Serve a single-page app located in src/main/resources/static

Shouldn't be that hard, but this question has been asked a dozen times in different ways, and there doesn't seem to be an answer. It's very easy to do in Dropwizard, or when you wire up Jersey and Jetty together directly.

The best answer so far is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331929/spring-catch-all-route-for-index-html):

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addViewController("/{spring:\\w+}")
            .setViewName("forward:/");
      registry.addViewController("/**/{spring:\\w+}")
            .setViewName("forward:/");
      registry.addViewController("/{spring:\\w+}/**{spring:?!(\\.js|\\.css)$}")
            .setViewName("forward:/");
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that calls to /api/bad_missing_path get routed to the SPA, and not to an error message that says this is a bad api call. The other problem with it is that I just don't understand it. Yet another problem is it explicitly mentions .js and .css file types, and I'm going to have many more types than that. I want everything that starts with /api to be treated as an api call, and everything that doesn't start with /api to get passed through to the /static directory.

I have also tried to mount the DefaultServlet on "/*" but it didn't catch anything, either using the default Tomcat server or when I switched to Jetty.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Can you provide any use case?