# Spring boot Regex to catch all routes

Tags: regex, spring, spring-boot, regex-group

Referring to [Spring catch all route for index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331929/spring-catch-all-route-for-index-html), I am trying out the regex `"/**/{spring:\\w+}"`to catch all routes. But I get the error:

**Tokenizing Error: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException, dangling metacharacter '*' at Index 2**

When I fix this by `"/\\*\\*/{spring:\\w+}"`, my regex fails to catch routes.

Requesting guidance regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation of the method:

> Patterns like "/static/**" or "/css/{filename:\w+\.css}" are allowed. See AntPathMatcher for more details on the syntax.

See [AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html). I assume `"/**/{spring:\\w+}"` needs to be changed at least to `"/**/{spring:\w+}"`

Comment: You are right. But at least this matches:
```java
boolean b = new AntPathMatcher().match("/**/{spring:\\w+}", "/foo/bar");
Assertions.assertTrue(b);
```